# Почему необходимо определение для чисто виртуального деструктора?

Tags: c++, классы, деструктор, виртуальная-функция

```
struct A {
    virtual ~A() = 0;
};
 
struct B : A {};

// A::~A() {}
 
int main() {
    B{};
}
```

Почему программа содержит ошибку линковки?

> undefined reference to `A::~A()'

Почему можно и нужно определять чисто виртуальную функцию?

Comment: Виртуальный деструктор будет вызываться. чисто виртуальную функцию тяжеловато вызвать. Поэтому, его нужно определять. Почему именно так? Так придумали создатели языка.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan если раскомментировать строку в вопросе, то всё работает, т.е. конструктор вызывается, хотя определение в базовом классе

Comment: Если раскомментировать,  то  это будет определение. Естественно не будет проблем. А выражение "всё работает", всегда остается не правильным, потому что даже при ошибке компиляции все работает с точки зрения приложения и сточки любого нормального зрения. Получение не правильного результата тоже является работой. Так что выражаться нужно правильно...

Comment: деструктор - это особая штука. Когда объект разрушается, то вначале вызывается его деструктор, а потом деструктор класса предка и так до самого базового. Когда у класса нет тела деструктора  (явного или неявного), то линковщик будет ругаться, так как ему он нужен.

Comment: @KoVadim зачем тогда разрешать конструкцию чисто виртуального деструктора, если он не может быть чисто виртуальным?

Comment: хороший вопрос. Но с++ это такой язык, который считает, что программист - умный человек и знает что делает. В с++ много годовых колец. Но зачем это было в таком виде оставлено - я не знаю, я не придумал явной причины, кроме как не усложнять компилятор.

Comment: Ну почему не может? Если вы создаете объекты только в динамической памяти, и не уничтожаете их до конца программы, то пуркуа бы и не па?...

Comment: вот только линковщику нужно объяснить, что программист решил не удалять объекты?

Answer (score 0):

Абстрактный базовый класс, это частичка порожденного класса. И он *может* иметь у себя указатель, конструктор, выделяющий память и деструктор, её освобождающий. И этот класс также имеет у себя и конструктор и деструктор.

Абстрактность заключается в запрещении реального создания объекта чисто данного класса. Но можно создавать объекты других классов, у которых он является базовым.

Виртуальность деструктора позволяет вызывать удаление объекта основываясь только по указателю на абстрактный класс.

```
# include <iostream>
class Base {
public  :
    Base    ();
    virtual ~Base   ()=0;
private :
    int *   ip  ;
} ;

Base::Base(){
    std::cout<<"Base()"<<std::endl;
    ip = new int[10];
}

Base::~Base(){
    std::cout<<"~Base()"<<std::endl;
    delete[]ip;
}

class Son : public Base {
public  :
    Son    ();
    virtual ~Son   ();
} ;

Son::Son():Base(){
    std::cout<<"Son()"<<std::endl;
}

Son::~Son(){
    std::cout<<"~Son()"<<std::endl;
}

int main(){
    Base    *   b = new Son;
    // вызов виртуального деструктора + удаляется объект Son
    delete  b   ;
    // реальный объект абстрактного класса создавать нельзя
    // Base    *   bp  =   new Base;
}
```

смотрим как создаются и уничтожаются объекты :

```
Base()
Son()
~Son()
~Base()
```

Comment: `Виртуальность заключается в запрещении реального создания объекта типа базового виртуального класса.` - а можно это как то детальнее расписать? а то выглядит суперстранно.

Comment: Текст Вы поправили, но как оно отвечает на вопрос - я не знаю.

Comment: .. потому-что деструктор **должен** быть вызван для всех классов родителей. @KoVadim как ещё объяснить, что объект абстрактного класса это такое-же живое *существо* (объект). Просто оно внутри другого объекта.

Comment: да, в этом и вся сложность ответа. Нужно найти правильные слова и их правильно соединить.

Answer (score 0):

Пока деструктор не определен, не возможно удалять объекты, созданные на  его базе. Виртуальный деструктор  делает возможным удалять объекты, при обращении к родителю.  Чисто виртуальный деструктор обычно не применяется, но не значит, что не может применяться.

> зачем тогда разрешать конструкцию чисто виртуального деструктора, если
> он не может быть чисто виртуальным?

Ну а зачем запрещать?
Можно придумать примеры, когда чисто виртуальный или защищенный деструктор  может стать инструментом для решения конкретной задумки,  также, как и удаленный или защищенный конструктор. Посмотрим на простом примере:

//file a.h

```
struct A {
    //или наследник класса, имеющий такой деструктор
    virtual ~A() = 0;
    //много полезных функций, например
    template<class Piece>
    Piece* CreatePiece()
    {
        return new Piece;
    }
};
#ifdef Core
A::~A() {};
#endif // Core
```

//file m.h

```
#define Core
#include "a.h"
```

//деструктор "А" определен

```
struct Builder : A { /*... */};
struct D {
    //можно пользоваться строителем
    Builder b;
            
};
```

//file X

```
#include "a.h"
//деструктор  "А"  не определен
struct My_locale : A {};
//нельзя пользоваться объектом класса
//не разрешен вызов  деструктора базового класса
```